# SWIG C++ to Python: Warning(362): operator= ignored

Tags: c++, python, swig

I am exporting a C++ class to Python and I noticed that during compilation, SWIG issued the following warning:

```
Warning(362): operator= ignored
```

I am not sure why the operator is being overloaded, because it says in the [SWIG documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn24), that SWIG is capable of handling operators such as the assignment operator

There is nothing special about my class, it is declared like this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    Foo& operator= (const Foo&); 
    // etc ..
};
```

Why is SWIG failing to generate wrapper code for the assignment operator, and how may I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no assignment in python (other than in primitive types), only assignment of pointers. If you want to create a copy, you need a special copy function.

Answer (score 9):

Read the last line of your [documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn24) link (section 31.3.11):

> Also, be aware that certain operators don't map cleanly to Python. For instance, overloaded assignment operators don't map to Python semantics and will be ignored.